# Unexpected = in haml file after updating Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am running a rails application (rails: 4.2 and ruby 2.2.3). I am trying to update my ruby to 2.4.4 and have been able to successfully run bundle install. However, when I start the server and go to the home page of my application, I encounter a unexpected = in the application.html.haml file for this line: 
= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'
Has anyone here encountered an error like this?

P.S. if this question has been posted before can someone redirect me to it as I cannot find this problem.

```
   %head

    %base{:href => "/dashboard"}
    %title Title Page
    = favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => nil
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body{'ng-app'=>'thumper','ng-controller'=>'MainController'}
    - if signed_in?
      .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top{:style => 'padding-top:0px;height: 30px;'}
        .container
          %button.navbar-toggle{"data-target" => ".navbar-collapse", "data-toggle" => "collapse"}
          %a.navbar-brand{:href => "/", :target => "_self"}
            = image_tag "main_image.png", :style => 'width:65px;', :alt => 'company_name'

          .navbar-collapse.collapse
            %ul.nav.navbar-nav
              %li
                %a{:href => "/faq", :target => "_self"}
                  %i.fa.fa-lightbulb-o
                  FAQ
              %li
```

This is my initial part of my application.html.haml file. I get the following error:

```
DEPRECATED: Please use restforce (https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) instead.
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.11 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.7.2 codename Bachmanity)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:3000, CTRL+C to stop


Started GET "/testpage" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-12 09:32:47 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (44.9ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by TestController#foo as HTML
HERE
  Rendered test/foo.html within layouts/application (2.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1964ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ExecJS::RuntimeError - SyntaxError: [stdin]:959:20: unexpected =:
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml___861496224579637971_70314333220700'
  app/lib/cors.rb:12:in `call'
  app/lib/cors.rb:12:in `call'



Started POST "/__better_errors/1f18681361fed4ae/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-12 09:32:50 -0500
```

The web  browser looks like this:

[image]

Comment: please put your code in a code block  as well as stack trace errors.  Look for the `{}}` icon in the editor to wrap your code

Comment: I did what you asked

Comment: Check your assets, some times when there's an asset compilation error it is not shown properly on the error page (try removing the javascript and stylesheet lines for a quick test). If removing one of those lines fixes the error then you need to inspect your assets, try `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile` too.